# How does arrow function behaves in Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Here is a sample of Javascript Object using traditional function definition

```
const obj = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  add: function(){
     return this.a + this.b;
  }
}

obj.add()  // returns 30
```

When I use arrow function in add, the context of `this` in add changes to global i.e. `windows` object in browser.

```
const obj = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  add: () => {return this.a + this.b}
}

obj.add()  // this context is global(windows) of it returns NaN
```

So in order to bind the context back to obj, I implemented call as below:

```
obj.add.call(obj)  // Still the context is global(windows) and returns NaN
```

So 2 things that I didn't understand is:

1. Why didn't the arrow function bind `obj` context by default as in traditional function definition?
2. Why didn't the `obj`'s add method get bind to the `obj` even if I've passed it explicitly?

Comment: *"1. Why did the arrow function didn't bind obj context by default as in traditional function definition?"* Because it closes over the context in which it's created, which is the context *around* the `const obj = {}`. Object literals don't have their own context. (You are **not** the first person to assume they did! Not by far. :-) ) *"2. Why didn't the obj's add method get bind to the obj even if I've passed it explicitly?"* Same answer: Arrow functions *close over* `this`. They don't have `this` set by how they're called like traditional functions do.

Comment: And what about the first case? Using traditional function declaration? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I'm probably covering ground covered by the linked answers, but FWIW, check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/fpL51hmx/).

Comment: Traditional functions get `this` set by how they're called, not where they're defined. When you call a function via an object property (`obj.add()`), `this` within the call is set to `obj`. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). (FWIW, I also go into this [on my old anemic blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) and in my recent book [links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: So there are limitations to Js, `bind`/`call` doesn't work for all context? Is that what I shall interpret from now?

Comment: It's not a limitation, it's a feature. If you want to control `this` when you call the function (including syntax like `obj.add()` or using `bind` or `call` to set `this`), use a traditional function (created via the `function` keyword or method syntax). If you want a function that closes over `this`, use an arrow function. The chief motivation for adding arrow functions was to have them close over `this` so they'd be useful as callbacks within object methods.

Comment: I thought arrow functions were replacement to traditional functions. Seems that both go hand to hand :) Thank you for your explaination. Appreciated it.

Comment: Right, they're an adjunct, not a replacement. My pleasure! Happy coding!